# Elementary OS Display

Tags: display

I am new to Linux and still learning how to do very simple things. I wanted to make the text on the screen larger, so I went to System Settings/ Display and I clicked on some option I had at the bottom of the window, I do not remember the names of the two options given. The display is bigger now but I cant's see the whole windows, just the top part  and I can't go back to how it was because the option is at the bottom part of the window and I can't see it on the screen. What can I do?

Comment: Solved with tab and enter. Read this at some other message.